# VideoWriter.open is getting failed every time

Tags: opencv

```
bool CVideoCap::m_InitializeVidWriter(VideoCapture objVidCap,VideoWriter objVidWriter,string FileName)
{
    m_GetFrameDimensionandFPS(objVidCap);
    string vid;
    strcpy(FileName,vid);
cout<< "FileName = " << FileName<<endl;
    int codec = CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G');
    bool bVidWriterOpenCheck = objVidWriter.open(vid, codec,m_FPS,
                                Size(this->m_nframe_width,m_nframe_height), true);
    cout<< "bVidWriterOpenCheck = " << bVidWriterOpenCheck<<endl;
    return bVidWriterOpenCheck;

}
```

in this videowriter open function when i pass path of the filename through a string variable it gets failed but when i give hard coded path directly into the argument it works.
Please advice something.

Answer (score 0):

In line 4, the string *vid* has not been initialised.
In the strcpy call, in line 5, the second variable, i.e. vid is acting as the source and FileName as destination.
Try this,

```
strcpy(vid,FileName);
```

Should work now.